# Cannot load underlying module for 'UIKit' error

Tags: swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit, ios12

`Xcode` cannot load `UIKit` module. I got this error message:

```
// import UIKit - Cannot load underlying module for 'UIKit'
```

I downloaded this GitHub source project: [ARMuseum](https://github.com/code-and-co/ARMuseum/tree/master).

My xcode version:

```
Version 9.4 beta
```

Comment: It looks like internal Xcode 9.4 bug. On Version 10.0 (10A254a) everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode 9.4.1 in macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 everything works fine.

*It's definitely **a bug of Xcode 9.4 beta***.

> So, install the latest public version of Xcode to get rid of this bug.

[image]